# Webpack 2.2.0-rc.2 - Prevent build fail when there are eslint issues

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, eslint

I'm using **webpack 2.2.0-rc.2** with **eslint-loader 1.6.1** and **eslint 3.12.2**:

The **build fails** and the **process exits with code 2** when I have some eslint errors in my file.

Now, 
I want to prevent it, 
is there any solution?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? You can just not use eslint-loader.

Comment: @Gothdo I want to u se eslint, I just want no break my build. It should report issue but not causing build-pipeline to break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partially Fixed.

If you have a look at: 
https://github.com/MoOx/eslint-loader/blob/master/index.js#L102

you will know that where is at least one error the `emitter` is always set up to `webpack.EmitError` and that is not configurable.

[image]

#### workaround

Because of the `line 109` as `if(config.emitError)` if you pass `emitWarning = true` then, the emitter is overriden and no more emitError are passed to webpack.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following into your configuration:

```
plugins: [
   new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
     test: /\.js$/,
     options: {
       eslint: {
         // options
       }
     }
   })
]
```

I'm not certain whether this would help, since it's odd that your build fails when all the control options are disabled by default, but at least it will allow you to pass options to the loader.

Comment: it depends by the `eslint-loader`, it don't take care about configs... it's buggy. the only available fix is on my answer.

Comment: @Hitmands right, might help if you fork with a PR and use your repo in the meantime, seems like that's the only solution